# Smack XMPP - The connection is no longer connected. done=true smResumptionPossible=false

Tags: java, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am using Smack java library (version 4.3.1) (JDK 8). After some random time I sometimes get the following exception. Is there any way to avoid it?

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: The connection [...] (117) is no longer connected. done=true smResumptionPossible=false at
org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfDoneAndResumptionNotPossible(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1320) at
org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwNotConnectedExceptionIfAppropriate(XMPPTCPConnection.java:359) at 
org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.sendStanza(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:688)
```

The XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(
        ).setSecurityMode(
            ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled
        ).setXmppDomain(
            this.domain
        ).setHostAddress(
            InetAddress.getByName(
                this.host
            )
        )
        .allowEmptyOrNullUsernames(
        ).performSaslAnonymousAuthentication(
        ).build();
```

The XMPPTCPConnection:

```
conn.setReplyTimeout(30 * 1000);
conn.setUseStreamManagement(true);
conn.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
conn.connect();
conn.login();
```

Maven Central artifacts:

```
    <artifactId>smack-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>

    <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>

    <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>

    <artifactId>smack-java7</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>

    <artifactId>smack-resolver-dnsjava</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
```

Additional info:
The thing is that the `conn.isConnected` returns true. Internally, before sending a stanza (`conn.sendStanza`), Smack performs these checks: If (`conn.isConnected`) then if(`conn.isSmResumptionPossible`) then `sendStanza()`. If the `conn.isSmResumptionPossible()` returns false, then the exception that I get is thrown.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @alla See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531282/2441104).

Answer (score 1):

Install a connection listener and reconnect if the listener's callback tells you that the connection went down.

Comment: I had that idea. The thing is that the conn.isConnected returns true. Internally, before sending a stanza (conn.sendStanza), Smack performs these checks: If (conn.isConnected) then if(conn.isSmResumptionPossible) then sendStanza. If the conn.isSmResumptionPossible returns false, then the exception that I get is thrown.

Comment: No, that is not was happening. You are missing that `throwNotConnectedExceptionIfDoneAndResumptionNotPossible()`, invokes `done()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what `done()` does and how it affects the connection?
The `connectionClosed()` listener method is called only by the manual call of the `disconnect()` method. (Correct me if I am wrong) So, should I use `connectionClosedOnError()` listener method instead?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @HKumar See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531282/2441104)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what has helped me alleviate the issue:

```
 final XMPPTCPConnection conn = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);  
 conn.setReplyTimeout(30_000);
 conn.setUseStreamManagement(true);
 conn.setUseStreamManagementResumption(true);
 conn.setPreferredResumptionTime(5);
 ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(conn).enableAutomaticReconnection();
 PingManager.getInstanceFor(conn).setPingInterval(60);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have applied same settings you have describe. I am using smack ver 4.3.4 in my android app.

{SocketTimeoutException@14486} "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to msgsvc.panetny.com/64:ff9b::43d6:812c (port 5222) from /2402:3a80:86f:235f:c9dd:2897:8728:7e54 (port 42758) after 30000ms"

I have checked everything like my firewall, antivirus etc but no luck. I can able to connect with Spark application in windows 10 but get connected successfully but can't able to connect with android smack library. If you find any solution then please share a sample code.